# Textbox ScrollBar is not coming after setting ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have silverlight web app.I am showing log information in child windows.child window contain a textbox control.I have set ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" but vertical scroll bar is not showing up.please help me on this.

XAML

```
<controls:ChildWindow x:Class="LogPopUpWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
       Width="600" Height="400" 
       Title="" HasCloseButton="False">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="LogEvents" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"></TextBox>
    <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,0,0" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

C#

```
 public void RefreshLogs(string message = "")
    {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            if (Logger.GetLogs() != null)
            {
                Logger.GetLogs().ForEach(b =>
                {
                    text.AppendFormat("{2}{0}:  {1}{2}", b.UserTargetOperation, b.UserEventDate.ToString(), Environment.NewLine);
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in b.Parameters)
                    {
                        text.AppendFormat("         {0} : {1}{2}", pair.Key, pair.Value, Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                });
            }

            LogEvents.Text = text.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            LogEvents.Text = message;
            LogEvents.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        }
    }
```

Button Handler Coder

```
private void ShowLogLink_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ///Logger.GetLogs();
        ///
        LogPopUpWindow win = new LogPopUpWindow();
        win.RefreshLogs();
        win.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Am I missing something?.This is all code i have.

Answer (score 0):

I would put this just in a comment but I don't have enough rep.  I tried to reproduce the error you are describing of that the Vertical Scroll bar is not displaying, but when I fill the textbox with more text than it's height holds, the scroll bar shows.

Is there any other portions influencing your problem that you did not list?

Comment: Apart from this I have button handler code where I am launching the child window.This is all code I have.I have tried in different sample as well There also I am not getting TextBox scrollbar.Updated the question

Comment: This is a stretch, but maybe try await on the win.RefreshLog(). I don't really have a way to test this, but perhaps 'win' is getting rendered prior to the text being filled and the height getting set.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved.I added vertical scroll properties in the code and it is working.

```
public void RefreshLogs(string message = "")
    {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            if (Logger.GetLogs() != null)
            {
                Logger.GetLogs().ForEach(b =>
                {
                    text.AppendFormat("{2}{0}:  {1}{2}", b.UserTargetOperation, b.UserEventDate.ToString(), Environment.NewLine);
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in b.Parameters)
                    {
                        text.AppendFormat("         {0} : {1}{2}", pair.Key, pair.Value, Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                });
            }

            LogEvents.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto; // added
            LogEvents.Text = text.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            **LogEvents.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;** // added
            LogEvents.Text = message;
            LogEvents.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        }
    }
}
```